# How de degrade the CDM manifest version number to 1.0.15 in Data Factory?

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-factory, common-data-service

Power BI is able to consume Common Data Model manifest files version 1.0.15. However whenever I sink data in Data Factory to CDM inline dataset it set it to unsupported version number 1.1.0. Power BI does not understand the concept of rootlocation and globpattern I think.

Question? In Data Factory how do I change the schema version of an inline CDM dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When entities in a dataflow are mapped to a Common Data Model standard entity, such as Account, the version of that standard entity is included in the dataflow definition (model.json). Existing versions of the Common Data Model standard entities will persist unchanged, so existing dataflows won't be affected. If you'd like to leverage new versions of the Common Data Model standard entities, you can edit existing dataflows, but your changes might affect reports and dashboards that use the dataflow.

Workaround for this is to create Common Data Model manifest file and try changing `"jsonSchemaSemanticVersion"`

To create Common Data Model manifest file refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/creating-schemas#create-the-manifest)

Sample code -

```
{
    "jsonSchemaSemanticVersion": "1.0.15",
    "imports": [],
    "manifestName": "clickstream",
    "explanation": "CDM standard entities",
    "entities": [{
            "type": "LocalEntity",
            "entityName": "ReverseIp",
            "entityPath": "ReverseIp.cdm.json/ReverseIp"
        },
        {
            "type": "LocalEntity",
            "entityName": "Session",
            "entityPath": "Session.cdm.json/Session"
        },
        {
            "type": "LocalEntity",
            "entityName": "UserAgent",
            "entityPath": "UserAgent.cdm.json/UserAgent"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more information - [ADF Adds Support for Inline Datasets and Common Data Model to Data Flows](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/adf-adds-support-for-inline-datasets-and-common-data-model-to/ba-p/1441798)